# Three.js exports Blender model without texture

Tags: three.js, blender

I am trying to export this https://www.dropbox.com/s/zz1g38xaci2ibod/sailor.blend?dl=1 Blender model using exporter from Three.js 73 (from github master branch).

But when I load it I see no texture:

```
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load("assets/sailor.json",
            function (geom, mat) {
                console.log(mat);
                var model = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat[0]);

                model.castShadow = true;

                scene.add(model);
            });
```

[image]

The model has two meshes (body and eyes) but looks like this exporter can export only one mesh... So for now I exported without eyes.

[image]

Exporter settings:

[image]

Exporter output file: [sailor.json](https://gist.github.com/AlexP11223/0ba35b9eae4a0343e68e2a2c18a9f4ec)

io_three.export.log is empty with any logging level.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will solve your problem but it might atleast give you a hint of where the problem is.

I compared my converted JSON files and compared to yours, and noticed that the JSON file that you use does not specify what texture the object should use.

Add:

`"mapDiffuse" : "nameoftexture.png",`

to your

```
"materials: [{
    ...,
    ...,
    ...
}]"
```

array.

Good luck.

**EDIT**

Your model seems to work with textures for me when I added this line to the materials property array.

Comment: Yes, I know that my JSON does not contain textures. But I don't have any texture file to specify it manually. At least not as a single file, if I unpack "External Data" from .blend I get multiple texture files (skin, cloth, etc.). I thought that exporter should somehow export it and specify in JSON. By the way I have not created this model, I took it from blendswap (CC0).

Comment: Sorry for bothering, but this worked perfectly for me, albeit a hacky solution in my opinion. Do you know why blender doesn't do this by default when exporting? I had my diffuse maps set up correctly.